# how to rewrite given urls

Tags: mod-rewrite

how can i rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/someURLhere
```

into

```
www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=someURLhere
```

without mistaking local files, and directories as domains.

so i dont want

```
www.mysite.com/index.php 
www.mysite.com/admin/
```

to rewrite to

```
www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=index.php
www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=admin/
```

Comment: You might want to mention the webserver you are using since mod_rewrite does exist for more webservers than Apache httpd.

Answer (score 2):

try this hacked joomla's htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ping.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ping.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be easier to redirect urls in a "virtual" sub folder that does not actually exist. I'm not sure if that will work for your design but I would definitely recommend considering it since it will make your life easier when writing the Rewrite rules and also prevents you from accidently rewriting a file that exists.

```
www.mysite.com/p/someURLhere
```

(where /p/ does not actually exist on the filesystem)
redirects to
    www.mysite.com/ping.php?url=someURLhere

Then your rewrite rule would need less conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

What DennyHalim said

I hacked it a bit more (didn't try it but it looks right :s  )

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ping.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ping.php?url=$1 [L]
```

basically says 
'if the url doesn't point to a file that exists'
'if th url doesn't point to a directory that exists'
'if the url is not "/ping.php"'
'match everything'
'rewrite to "ping.php?url=$1"'